# What are the consequences of blocking incoming UDP port 68 on my computer?

Tags: networking, freebsd, firewall, dhcp, ipfw

In a FreeBSD 13.1 install, I enabled the IPFW firewall and set `firewall_type="workstation"` in `/etc/rc.conf`. This allows outgoing requests, while denying incoming requests. When I checked the firewall log at `/var/log/security`, I see this entry:

```
Apr  5 12:34:56 mycomputer kernel: ipfw: 65500 Deny UDP 192.168.1.1:67 192.168.1.123:68 in via wlan0
```

It seems that the firewall is blocking UDP packets from the DHCP server (`192.168.1.1`). Would this cause issues when the DHCP lease expires?

Comment: `firewall_type="workstation"` should know better than to block 67 & 68.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Would this cause issues when the DHCP lease expires?"

Yes.

> DHCP uses UDP as its transport protocol.  DHCP messages from a
> client    to a server are sent to the 'DHCP server' port (67), and
> DHCP    messages from a server to a client are sent to the 'DHCP
> client' port    (68).

Source: [RFC 2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131)